# How to clear data when back button pressed

Tags: flutter, dart

I've 2 pages, and each of these pages have the same function in `initState` that return a list.

The first page has the regular function, the second page has the same function but with filter that return filtered list.

The problem is when i press on the "back button" in the second page and go back to the first page, I am getting the filtered list instead of the regular list.

How do i "clear" the data from the second page before going to the first page?

The function:

```
  Future fetchProducts({flag = false})  {
  return http
        .get(
            'MyAddress')
        .then<Null>((http.Response response) {
      final Map<String, dynamic> listData = json.decode(response.body); 
      listData.forEach((String id, dynamic fetchedData) {
        final Product product = Product(
          id: id, 
          address: fetchedData['address'],
          image: fetchedData['imageUrl'],
        );
        fetchedData.add(product);   
      });
      _product = flag
          ? fetchedData.where((Product product) {        
              return product.userId == 1;
            }).toList()
                     : fetchedData;
    });
  }
```

Comment: please add some code to your post. Specifically on how you pass the list from one page to another.

Comment: @George I updated the quesiton

Comment: I see a double shadowed declaration of `fetchedData` variable. I assume there is a global `List<...> fetchedData;` variable, and `dynamic fetchedData` in `forEach` closure. I believe you should rename one.

Comment: As for the problem described in the question - it's still not clear to me how you pass variables from one screen to another. I can't see how this function is relevant to the actual problem.

Comment: That exactly was my point, I don't pass variables from One page to another. 
@George You can see in the end of the function the if statement, depending on the flag. If the flag is true - filteted list, if flas is false - regular list. The problem was when i navigate from the regular list page to the filtered list page, i get the filtered list, but when i come back to regular list page, i still get the filtered list

Comment: Can you show the code where `_product` variable is used? As well as `fetchedData` one?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two ways of triggering actions when going back to a page (route).

1)

```
void WaitforBeingBackfromConfig() async{
    await Navigator.push(
      context, MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (context) => ConfigScreen('platzhalter'))
    );

//Do something right after return to page1
  }
```

2) As stated before by @Michael: WillPopScope:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: _SaveAndBack,
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Config'),
        ),
        body: Column(children: <Widget>[
     ....    ]),
      ),
    );
```

This calls the function "_SaveAndBack" before page2 is left.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if this is the best solution, but I can wrap my `Scaffold` with `WillPopScope`, and navigate from there with `Navigator.pushReplacementNamed` to the previous screen to "activate" the `initState` again

Answer (score 1):

#Application Root

```
 return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: () async {
        data1 = '';
        data2 = 0;
        Navigator.pop(context);
        return true;
      },
      child:scaffold...
```